# Connect to a remote MariaDB server using VirtualMin

Tags: linux, mariadb, virtualmin

I have a web server but wish to locate a separate server for MariaDB. I'm following this [tutorial](https://archive.virtualmin.com/documentation/database/remote#:%7E:text=Login%20to%20Virtualmin%2C%20and%20go,by%20Webmin%20connecting%20to%20MySQL.) but there's no "Module Config" under Webmin -> Servers -> MariaDB Database Server. Here's the [MariaDB config page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvXRX.png). I look into all the other menus and nothing allows me to set the IP of my remote database server.

Comment: You should change the config in web server to point to remove database

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. I just don't know where to change it...haha.